# when data added from drop down list the data should no longer be in drop down list

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

i am trying to show only those countries name from drop down list which doesn't exist in database, for example if i add 'Bottles' to database the value 'Bottles' should no longer be in drop down list.

form.indx

```
<div class="form-group" id="frm_packages">
<select class="form-control" id="packages" name="packages"title="packages">

         <option value="Pack">Pack</option>
         <option value="Bottles">Bottles</option>
         <option value="Cartons">Cart</option>
         <option value="Boxes">Boxes</option>
         <option value="Cans">Cans</option>
         <option value="Bags">packages</option>
</select>
<div class="d-inline"></div>
</div>
```

//scripts show data

```
var table = $('#packageTable').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    aaSorting: [[2, 'asc']],
    stateSave: true,
    processing: true,
    serverSide : false,
    bSortable: true,
    responsive : true,
    autoWidth : false,
    order: [[0, 'desc']],
    buttons: [
        'create', 'print', 'reload'
    ],

    ajax: '{{route('admin.packages.index')}}',
    columns: [
        {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
        {data: 'name', name: 'name'},

    ],
});
```

//Adding new data

```
$(document).on('click','#btnSave', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('admin.packages.store') }}",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            name: $('#packages').val(),

        },
        success:function(data){
            if (data.status == true) {
                $('#new').modal('hide');
                frm.trigger('reset');
                table.ajax.reload( null, false );
                Toast.fire({
                  type: 'success',
                  title: 'added successful'
                })
            }
        },

    });
});
```

//Controller

```
public function index(PackageDataTable $dataTable)
{
    return $dataTable->render('admin.packages.index');
}


public function store(Request $request)
{
     request()->validate(['name'=>['required','unique:packages'],]);
     Package::create(request()->all());
     return response()->json(array("status"=>true));
}
```

//model

```
protected $fillable = ['name'];    

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
}
```

what should i do for not showing the existing data in drop down list

Comment: Do you have any back-end code? Controller, Model?

Comment: we really need to see your php code.   You've tagged this php but there's no php code there.  But basically you would, in php, generate your list of countries for the drop down after you get the list in the database.  If you had a master list, you would simply remove if exists.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, you should fetch all your data and then you must assign it to the `js` variables one by one because `javascript` is the language which will work for you on the client-side on your page. And then finally for the dropdown by applying `if{}`, `else{}` conditions you can get the desired results.